# i cant change the segments with the bevel tool

Tags: bevel

[image: i want to this circle to have 3 segments but it isn't working i tried to enable global undo but it isn't working as well]

i want to this circle to have 3 segments but it isn't working i tried to enable global undo but it isn't working as well. i tried to see in the internet but it wasn't working so can you help me, to thereby finishing me project

Comment: hello could you please share this object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Apply your scale rotation object, select object  ctrl A > rotation scale

Comment: Your width is 0, are you sure the vertices aren't being created, but exactly on top of the old ones?